# Comparar datos de una tabla de excel con una tabla de una base de datos sql con encriptación

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, excel, encriptación

Soy bastante nuevo en la programación en c# y usando datos encriptados y lo que estoy intentando hacer es un programa que compara los datos (DNI, fecha y hora) de una tabla de excel con los de una base de datos, si hay alguna fecha diferente en la base de datos, esta se debe cambiar y se debe usar la que viene en el excel. Pero para ello es necesario encriptar los datos antes de hacerlo.

El problema que tengo es que al depurar, mi programa no lee bien los datos o tiene la estructura bien porque me devuelve que loData.Rows.Count == 0. Que puedo estar haciendo mal para que no me detecte las filas de los dnis encriptados? Gracias, si es necesario alguna parte de código más la puedo aportar.

```
// Función para comparar las tablas SQL y Excel
void CompareTables(DataTable sqlTable, DataTable excelTable)
{
    Log("Iniciando la comparación de datos entre SQL y Excel.");
    try
    {
        // Crear una instancia de la clase BBDD.MySql
        BBDD.MySql m = new BBDD.MySql();

        //Obtener cadena de conexión
        string connectionString = m.getConnString();

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            foreach (DataRow excelRow in excelTable.Rows)
            {
                string Fecha = excelRow.Field<string>("Fecha cita");
                string Hora = excelRow.Field<string>(" Hora");                      
                string encryptedDocumento = excelRow.Field<string>("Documento"); // Accedemos a la columna "Documento" del archivo Excel
                      
            
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedDocumento))
                {
                    //pacientesSinDNI++;
                    Log(" \n El paciente con fecha: " + Fecha + " no tiene DNI \n");
                }

                else
                {                  
                    Log("Leyendo el DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);
                }

                
                Dictionary<string, object> loParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                loParams.Add("@numDocumento", encryptedDocumento);


                DataTable loData = m.GetDataTable(@"SELECT v.fecha, v.hora, p.numDocumento FROM `visita` v
                                                    LEFT JOIN paciente p ON p.id = v.idPaciente
                                                    WHERE fecha = '2023-12-13'
                                                    AND p.numDocumento = @numDocumento", loParams);



                //Log(encryptedDocumento + " es " + "numero de sql");

                if (loData.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    Log("La fila en el archivo Excel no existe en la tabla SQL");
                    // La fila en el archivo Excel no existe en la tabla SQL
                    //Log("Fila no encontrada en SQL para DNI: " + numDocumentoExcel);                   
                
                }else if (loData.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    string liIdVisita = loData.Rows[0]["IdVisita"].ToString();
                    DateTime loFechaExcel = DateTime.Parse(Fecha);
                    DateTime loFechaSQL = DateTime.Parse(loData.Rows[0]["fecha"].ToString());

                    // Comprobar si la fecha en el Excel es diferente de la fecha en la base de datos
                    if (loFechaExcel != loFechaSQL)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, string> loParams2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        loParams2.Add("@fecha", loFechaExcel.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                        loParams2.Add("@hora", Hora + ":00");
                        loParams2.Add("@IdVisita", liIdVisita);

                        Log("Fila encontrada en SQL para DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);

                        // Actualizar la fecha en la base de datos
                        m.ExeSql("update visita set fecha=@fecha, hora=@hora where id=@IdVisita", loParams2);
                        Log("Fecha actualizada en SQL para DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log("Comparación de datos entre SQL y Excel completada.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Error en CompareTables: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

He hecho el programa al revés desencriptando y me ha funcionado, pero a la inversa todavía no entiendo que problema tengo.

```
// Función para comparar las tablas SQL y Excel
void CompareTables(DataTable sqlTable, DataTable excelTable)
{
    Log("Iniciando la comparación de datos entre SQL y Excel.");
    try
    {
        // Crear una instancia de la clase BBDD.MySql
        BBDD.MySql m = new BBDD.MySql();

        //Obtener cadena de conexión
        string connectionString = m.getConnString();

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            foreach (DataRow excelRow in excelTable.Rows)
            {
                //string numDocumentoExcel = excelRow.Field<string>("Documento");
                string Fecha = excelRow.Field<string>("Fecha cita");
                string Hora = excelRow.Field<string>(" Hora");


                
                string encryptedDocumento = excelRow.Field<string>("Documento"); // Accedemos a la columna "Documento" del archivo Excel
                //string encryptedDocumentoExcel = encrypt(documentoExcel); // Encriptamos "Documento"

                
            
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedDocumento))
                {
                    //pacientesSinDNI++;
                    Log(" \n El paciente con fecha: " + Fecha + " no tiene DNI");
                }

                else
                {                  
                    Log("Leyendo el DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);
                }

                
                Dictionary<string, object> loParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                loParams.Add("@numDocumento", encryptedDocumento);

                DataTable loData = m.GetDataTable(@"SET @@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
                                    SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
                                    SELECT v.fecha,v.hora,v.id as IdVisita
                                    FROM paciente p 
                                    JOIN visita v ON p.id = v.IdPaciente 
                                    WHERE v.fecha >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                                    AND CASE WHEN ifnull(p.numDocumento,'')='' THEN '' ELSE CAST(AES_DECRYPT(substr(FROM_BASE64(p.numDocumento), 17),'zL/xMMl7/LC36PoVbPwQGyXc/uzY1kTy', substr(FROM_BASE64(p.numDocumento),1,16)) AS CHAR) END = @numDocumento", loParams);

                Log("Comparando datos de " + encryptedDocumento + " con SQL \n ");
                //Log(encryptedDocumento + " es " + "numero de sql");

                if (loData.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                
                    // La fila en el archivo Excel no existe en la tabla SQL
                    //Log("Fila no encontrada en SQL para DNI: " + numDocumentoExcel);
              
                
                }else if (loData.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    //Comprobación de fecha y hora
                    if (Fecha != loData.Rows[0]["fecha"].ToString() || Hora != loData.Rows[0]["hora"].ToString() )
                    {
                        //Actualización en la base de datos
                        string liIdVisita = loData.Rows[0]["IdVisita"].ToString();
                        Dictionary<string, string> loParams2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        DateTime loFecha = DateTime.Parse(Fecha);
                        loParams2.Add("@fecha", loFecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); //yyyy-mm-dd
                        loParams2.Add("@hora", Hora + ":00");
                        loParams2.Add("@IdVisita", liIdVisita);

                        Log("Fila encontrada en SQL para DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);

                        


                        //update a mysql
                        m.ExeSql("update visita set fecha=@fecha,hora=@hora where id=@IdVisita", loParams2);


                        Log("Fecha actualizada en SQL para DNI: " + encryptedDocumento);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log("Comparación de datos entre SQL y Excel completada.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Error en CompareTables: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```